# Partition by Date Range in Window Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, window-functions

I'm trying to write a query that returns, **for each of the last 44 days, a count of the rentals made in the 7-day window preceding that day.**

This is tricky because not all dates in the set are consecutive, and dates without rentals are not rows in the data set.

Here is where I am downloading the data from:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

I know this requires the use of a WINDOW function and most likely, the conjunction of both the PREDICT BY and ORDER BY clauses, but my results are returning duplicate dates and the count column is displaying the same value for every row. Here is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('day', rental_date), count(rental_id) OVER w
FROM rental
GROUP BY rental_date, rental_id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY (rental_date BETWEEN DATE '2005-08-23' - INTERVAL '44days' AND DATE '2005-08-23') 
             ORDER BY rental_date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', rental_date) DESC;
```

The expected output would look something like:

```
       Col1                            Col2                               
date_trunc1                count(rental_id) 
2006-02-21 00:00:00                     182
2006-02-20 00:00:00                     182
2006-02-19 00:00:00                     182
2006-02-18 00:00:00                     182
2006-02-17 00:00:00                     182
2006-02-16 00:00:00                     182                           
2006-02-15 00:00:00                     182
2005-08-30 00:00:00                     598
2005-08-29 00:00:00                    1224
2005-08-28 00:00:00                    1883
2005-08-27 00:00:00                    2507  
2005-08-26 00:00:00                    3135
2005-08-25 00:00:00                    3756    
2005-08-24 00:00:00                    4349
2005-08-23 00:00:00                    3374
2005-08-22 00:00:00                    3148
2005-08-21 00:00:00                    2489
2005-08-20 00:00:00                    1865
2005-08-19 00:00:00                    1237
2005-08-18 00:00:00                     616
2005-08-17 00:00:00                      23
2005-08-16 00:00:00                       0
2005-08-08 00:00:00                     671
2005-08-07 00:00:00                    1305
```

*excluding dates that are not rows in the dataset, of course. This is why the 7 days preceding 2006-02-14 are all counted as 0.

Comment: Move the `BETWEEN` condition to the `WHERE` clause and have no `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I went ahead and made the changes you'd suggested, but I'm still receiving the same value all the way down in the count row and there are still a few duplicate dates

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rNrqGfu

Comment: You can see I'm experiencing the same problem on the scale of days by the link above. I found a few consecutive dates (08/16 - 08/23) to help serve the function of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't post any test data, I'll go by your description:

```
SELECT rental_date, count
FROM (SELECT rental_date::date,
             count(*) OVER (ORDER BY rental_date::date
                            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '6 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
      FROM rental
      WHERE rental_date::date BETWEEN current_date - (44 + 7)
                              AND current_date - 1
     ) subq
WHERE rental_date >= current_date - 44
ORDER BY rental_date;
```

Of course rows will be conted several times, because that is what you say you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! The query isn't returning anything, but I'll share the dataset here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

Comment: It's a little tricky, because not all of the dates are consecutive. So, in the case of dates '2005-08-21' to '2005-08-14' for example, the 16th through the 20th would be summed and the 14th and 15th would also be thrown in, but counted as zeros bc no rentals those days.

Comment: If you want me to understand what you just wrote, you'd have to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64327976/edit) the question and add sample data and the expected output (as text, not as images).

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. Please let me know if it's necessary that I clarify anything further.

Comment: If you want me to understand what you commented above, you'd have to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64327976/edit) the question and add sample data and the expected output (as text, not as images)

Comment: Hey there, I added the expected output, if that helps

Comment: Please also add a `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT` statements to populate the table. In your expected output, please show the numbers rather than a verbal description.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you had in mind. It's just weird bc dates like '2005-08-08' and  '2005-08-07' don't exist in the data set because no rentals took place on those days, but they would need to show up in the output because rentals did occur on '2005-08-01' and '2005-07-30' within the 7 days preceding.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but something like this should do.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('day', rental_date) rental_date, count(rental_id) cnt
    FROM rental
    WHERE rental_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '44 DAYS'
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT rental_date, SUM(cnt) OVER w
FROM t
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY rental_date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
ORDER BY rental_date DESC;
```

First you count rows per day and then you sum those up in order to get one row per day.

Comment: Hi! This is actually very close to what I'm looking for. I'm trying to get a rolling sum, but the output looks cumulative for unbounded preceding. I think a WHERE clause could also help limit the result to only the past x days.

Comment: @strapped_gopherbro You are right about the WHERE clause - best to filter dates inside the CTE. I'll fix the answer according to that.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and added a little extra context in the initial question, if that helps.

Comment: @strapped_gopherbro I'm done here. You are welcome to adjust the date filter to 51 days and add an additional external filter for 44 days, if that's what you need.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for implementing the WHERE clause, along with the date filter. The query still appears to be outputting a running sum though. I have to apologize if I haven't provided enough resources or context.