# Total Result by Column and Date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to this example.

| id | s_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 8 | 2022-03-23 |
| X | 9 | 2022-03-24 |
| X | 9 | 2022-03-24 |
| X | 10 | 2022-03-24 |

I need to get which s_id has been recorded how many times per day. First I thought of grouping and looping the dates and querying the s_id for that date. However, I know that this will cause a loss of performance on too many recordings.

How can I do it using INNER JOIN, JOIN?

**If there is no record for that s_id on that date, 0 should be assigned.**

I'm planning to get a result like

| date | s_id | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-23 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-03-23 | 9 | 0 |
| 2022-03-23 | 10 | 0 |
| 2022-03-24 | 8 | 0 |
| 2022-03-24 | 9 | 2 |
| 2022-03-24 | 10 | 1 |

Comment: you are doing this on a SQL database or on PHP arrays?

Comment: Why not grouping by `s_id` and `day` in your query? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097732/5103610

Comment: SQL TABLE. But I will loop it with php. I'll put it in a chart to observe the daily visitor differences between the sites.

Comment: @Almaju If there is no record for that s_id on any date, I can't get results.

Comment: Yes, obviously. You can then populate the missing rows in php or use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) but that might be overkill.
You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327976/partition-by-date-range-in-window-function

Comment: @Almaju I'm sure I can handle this in one query. More ideas are needed.

Comment: You can with window functions.

Comment: Please check MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.s_id, COUNT(t2.s_id) AS total
 FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.date, B.s_id FROM mytable A CROSS JOIN mytable B) t1
  LEFT JOIN mytable t2
  ON t1.date=t2.date
  AND t1.s_id=t2.s_id
GROUP BY  t1.date, t1.s_id
ORDER BY  t1.date, t1.s_id
```

The idea is to get each existing `s_id` attach with each existing `date` using a `CROSS JOIN` between the same table. Then make that as a subquery and do a `LEFT JOIN` with the same table again but this time to get the total count of each matching `s_id` and `date` from the third table. If no match, it should return `0`.
I suppose this query will work on almost all MySQL versions.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ad18ed1d54f1ddfdd52197ded522d245)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get which s_id has been recorded how many times per day.

That is simply

```
SELECT s_id, `date`, COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY s_id, `date`;
```

No `JOIN` needed.  Hauling all the data back to PHP is probably more costly than simply letting MySQL do all the work.

> If there is no record for that s_id on that date, 0 should be assigned.

OK, now it gets messier.  First, build a table with all the desired dates; let's call it `dates`.  (MariaDB has an easy way to do that.)

```
SELECT s.s_id, d.date, COALESCE(x.ct, 0)
    FROM       ( SELECT `date` FROM dates          ) AS d -- all the dates
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT s_id FROM tbl     ) AS s -- all the s_ids
    LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT s_id, `date`, COUNT(*) AS ct
                    FROM tbl GROUP BY s_id, `date`
               ) AS x   ON x.s_id = s.s_id
                       AND x.date = d.date
```